# implement file data and using Dijkstra function to work in python

Tags: python

I created a function by using dijkstra module to work on map shortest path.
And now, I'm trying to implement a file data and use that function to work on it.

Here is my function code:

```
nodes = {'A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E'}

edges = [('A', 'B', 3), ('B', 'A', 3), ('A', 'C', 5), ('C', 'A', 5), 
         ('A', 'E', 2), ('E', 'A', 2), ('B', 'D', 2), ('D', 'B', 2),
         ('D', 'C', 1), ('C', 'D', 1), ('C', 'E', 2), ('E', 'C', 2),
         ('D', 'E', 4), ('E', 'D', 4)]

g = (nodes, edges)
src = 'D'

prev, dist = dijkstra(g, src)
```

And here is my file data:

```
4 5 0.35
5 4 0.35
4 7 0.37
5 7 0.28
7 5 0.28
5 1 0.32
0 4 0.38
0 2 0.26
7 3 0.39
1 3 0.29
2 7 0.34
6 2 0.40
3 6 0.52
6 0 0.58
6 4 0.93
```

How to implement the file and replace the nodes and edges by the data of the file?

Answer (score 0):

```
nodes = set()
edges = list()
f = open('data.txt')
for line in f:
    node_1, node_2, length = line.split()
    nodes.add(node_1)
    nodes.add(node_2)
    edges.append((node_1, node_2, length))
```

will do the trick.